# Escape the asterisk, when used in a string (javascript)

Tags: javascript, escaping, javascript-objects

I am trying to search for any object key that has the value of `"*"` *Not the wildcard character*, but the string `"*"`.

How do I escape the asterisk in the following code? currently (and rightly so) this returns *every* property in the object.

```js
keys = Object.keys(fullListObj).filter((k) => fullListObj[k] === 'n/a' || '*');
```

Comment: `fullListObj[k] === 'n/a' || fullListObj[k] === '*'`

Comment: wow. I didnt realise it would be that simple. If you could answer the question with this, and a brief explanation of why, I will make it as accepted and correct.

Comment: because it is `(fullListObj[k] === 'n/a') || '*'` The code is not saying is it one of these two values. It is saying if it matches `'n/a')` string or this string is truthy. That string is always going to be truthy so everything is not going to be filtered out.

Comment: Thankyou, I see where I went wrong now.

Comment: `.filter(k => ['n/a','*'].includes(fullListObj[k]))`

Comment: I really like this concise method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your error was that you forgot to add this check `fullListObj[k] === "*"`
What you did is you asked if `fullListObj[k] === "n/a"` or `"*"`
and `"*"` is a string that is not empty so this will always evaluate to true.

You should change it to this:

```js
keys = Object.keys(fullListObj).filter(
  (k) => fullListObj[k] === "n/a" || fullListObj[k] === "*"
);
```

Comment: thankyou for the explanation, I will mark it as correct as soon as SO allows me to.